# How can I tell if a function is called in a loop within python's tracer function?

Tags: python, stack-trace, code-inspection

In the tracer callback set with python's `sys.settrace()`, I can get the function name, line number, etc. Now I want to know whether the current function being traced is called in a loop by its caller. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156023/print-current-call-stack-from-a-method-in-python-code.  Is this what you're looking for?